# Groovy syntax explaination

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I came across the below function,

```
def some_name = {a, b, c -> a==c?bumpUp(b):b}
```

although i can understand that this function is some sort of short hand (can't recall or figure out the long form). It taking the 3 arguments, comparing for equally of a & c, if equal calling another function

`bumpUp(b)`

So questions are:
1. is my assumption on the logic right?
2. what is the long way of writing this and what is it called?
3. what is the `:b` doing in the `bumpUp(b):b`

Comment: did some groovy reading. And this is explained in the section of 'closures'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ternary operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_ternary_operator) which involves both a ? and a : , is a short and clean way to use an equivalent to an if statement. Reduction of the code verbosity hence makes it more readable.

For example:

```
String result = (1==1) ? 'equals' : 'not equals'
```

Lets explain the line above:

If the condition (1==1) is true, then the result assignment will be **'equals'**, else the result assignment will be **'not equals'**.

The long way you probably familiar with is as follows:

```
String result = ""
if(1==1) {
    result = 'equals'
} else {
    result = 'not equals'
}
```

In order to answer your 3 questions:

1. Your assumption on the logic is right. :-)
2. The long way of writing it is described in the **question 2 section**.
3. The **:b** relates to the else section. the ':' is just a separator for the b variable.
   In case the if (a==c) is false then go to the section code after the ':' and in that particular case it is **b**.

**question 2 section**:

```
if(a==c){
    some_name = bumpUp(b)
} else {
    some_name = b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

?: operation is a ternary operator which involves both a ? and a : , like an if statement:

```
Boolean?true:false
```

equivalent to

```
if(Boolean)
    true
else
    false
```

EXCEPT that it returns the value true or false, so:

```
a==c?bumpUp(b):b
```

is like

```
if(a == c)
    return bumpUp(b)
else
    return b
```

Also note that groovy has a shorthand where you eliminate the center value called the "Elvis" operator.  It is often used to give variables a default value.  If you wanted to print out a name value but when it's null you don't want to print null, you might say:

```
println "Your name is ${name?:'unknown'}"
```

If the variable name doesn't have a value, it will print "unknown" instead of null but for "groovy true" (not null or empty) it will return the query value.